# Plezi route in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I've added [plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) into Gemfile and created such initializer:

```
#config/initializer/plezi.rb
class NewsPublisher
  def on_open
    binding.pry
  end
end

route '/ws', NewsPublisher
```

When I try to connect it via JS with this code `new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws");` I receive following error message on client side: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

On server side I have: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ws"):`

Can anybody explain how to use plezi routes in Rails app?

Answer (score 0):

In Plezi's [getting started guide](http://www.plezi.io/docs/basics#can-websockets-do-that), it states that:

> If your controller class defines an on_message(data) callback, plezi will automatically enable websocket connections for that route.

This statement should probably be repeated in the websockets and Rails guides... but I'm still writing the documentation and it isn't complete.

To make sure Plezi enables websockets for the `'/ws'` route, add an `on_message` callback (even an empty one). i.e.:

```
#config/initializer/plezi.rb
class NewsPublisher
  def on_open
    binding.pry
  end
  def on_message data
    puts "Websocket got: #{data}"
  end
end

Plezi.route '/ws', NewsPublisher
```

Please let me know if you have any issues.

**EDIT** (adding more information from the comments)

Plezi uses [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) as it's server, bypassing Rack's `hijack` API (Iodine is a fast C extension for Ruby, it acts as a Rack server, with native websockets support).

In Plezi's [guide to Plezi with Rails/Sinatra/Rack](http://www.plezi.io/docs/with_rack_app), it is stated that, when using Plezi in Rails/Sinatra/Rack:

> There's only one catch - **we can't have more than a single web-server per application. This means that our existing Rack application MUST use Plezi (Iodine, actually) as it's web server**.

Make sure to remove any servers from the Gemfile (i.e. `thin`, `puma`, `unicorn` etc').

*What about Apache (or Nginx) and Passenger?*

Apache can forward the requests to Iodine, much like a Proxy and similar to how Apache works together with puma, passenger, unicorn, thin and other app-servers.

It's possible to use Apache or Nginx, but **not** passenger.

*Performance?*

Test and see.

Iodine is a C extension that utilizes either `epoll` or `kqueue` system calls - which are very fast and built for concurrency. Also, Iodine has a very good memory management design, where Ruby objects passed to "Ruby-land" are often recycled or cleared to allow for optimized performance... but that's all just word. There is only one way to know - test.

Comment: Just added on_message method, but it doesn't fix issue, I have same errors.

Comment: @SergeiStruk I assume you restarted the application...? I'm a bit surprised. I will get to my laptop in a bit to experiment. The only difference I can think of (I have an app with Rails and Plezi) is that I might have written `Plezi.route` instead of just `route`...

Comment: I have class for the next two hours... For now, please post the gem file and make sure you're not using a different server (don't use `thin` or `puma`) or a gem that would add it's own server.

Comment: I've used thin. Its removing fixed the issue. What servers does plezi support? I use Passenger and Apache on production.

Comment: Plezi runs it's own server, called Iodine. It bypasses Rack's `hijack` API, for better websockets support (features and performance). It's not as fast for Http, because it's written in Ruby (not C).

Comment: so I cannot use Passenger and Apache  on production, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95612/discussion-between-sergei-struk-and-myst).

Comment: Apache will forward the requests to Iodine and act as a Proxy (similar to how  Apache works together with passenger). You can use Apache, but you can't use passenger.